# Angular 2 adding Markdown addon

Tags: angular

I tried to add [angular2-markdown](https://github.com/dimpu/angular2-markdown) to my angular script but after adding it
to app.module.ts my browser throws an error and do not load the app.

I install the app via npm and added it to app.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
imports:      [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    JsonpModule,
    routing,
    FormsModule,
    MarkdownModule.forRoot(),
],
```

I do not use it write now anywhere in the app. After removing it form imports in app.module.js everything runs fine again.

Do I miss something? I never used 3rd party plug-ins before. 
The following error message was thrown, if somebody understand what angluar want to say with it.

```
    Error: (SystemJS) expected expression, got '<'
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:15:27
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:7:20
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:2
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
    Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:24
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:52
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25
    ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:21
    invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1364:9
    globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1382:17

    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2-markdown
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
Stack trace:
(SystemJS) expected expression, got '<'
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:15:27
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js:1:2
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:7:20
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:31
    @http://localhost:3000/app/main.js:1:2
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:391:17
    Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:141:24
    scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:831:52
    ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:424:17
    Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:191:28
    drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:595:25
    ZoneTask.invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:502:21
    invokeTask@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1364:9
    globalZoneAwareCallback@http://localhost:3000/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:1382:17

    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/angular2-markdown
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/app.module.js
    Evaluating http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
    Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/main.js
```

Comment: this is probably something better off answered on github issues, as I've seen you've already reported.  have you installed the module through `npm` and imported it into the module file? `import { MarkdownModule } from 'angular2-markdown';`

Comment: I already post it to github, but I am not sure if it is my issue or one from angular2-markdown.

Comment: just starting with the obvious and working towards the obscure, did you import the module before trying to use it?